# drawing a rainbow with canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, drawing

Hello everyone I am trying to draw a simple rainbow in canvas by using half circles. My first circle was created an worked perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<script> 
var omkadering = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = omkadering.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();`
context.arc(95,100,80,3.1,2*Math.PI);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = "violet";
context.stroke();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this actually worked fine I had the first layer done 
[first layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huj9a.jpg)

then I tried to make the second one so I added this part

```
context.strokeStyle = "violet";
-- started new code here --
context.closePath();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(95,120,80,3.1,2*Math.PI);
context.strokeStyle = "indigo";
-- new code ends here --
context.stroke();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it overwrites the old layer

[layer 2 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAC7w.jpg)

I tried several other methods too, like making a new variable context or separating them from each other but none helped

does anyone had an idea what I do wrong or forgot to add ?

thanks in advance !

Ian Dessers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to change the radius of the arc, not the centre.

```js
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

var arcWidth = 10;
var radius = 8 * arcWidth;

var omkadering = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = omkadering.getContext("2d");
omkadering.width = (radius + (colors.length-0.5) * arcWidth) * 2;
omkadering.height = (radius + (colors.length-1) * arcWidth);

var drawArc = function( color ){
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(
    omkadering.width/2,
    omkadering.height + arcWidth/2,
    radius,
    Math.PI,
    2*Math.PI
  );
  context.lineWidth = arcWidth;
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
  radius += arcWidth;
};

colors.reverse().forEach( drawArc );
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a rainbow with a radial gradient:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var cx=cw/2;
var cy=ch/2;

draw();

function draw() {
  var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(cx,ch,50,cx,ch,100);
  var stop=1/8;
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*0, 'transparent');
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*7, 'red');
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*6, 'orange');
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*5, 'yellow');
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*4, 'green')
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*3, 'blue');
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*2, 'Indigo');
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*1, 'violet');
  gradient.addColorStop(stop*8, 'transparent');
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=125></canvas>
```

Comment: that looks pretty nice ! :) thank you for the reply !

Comment: I think only double rainbows get their colors in this way, so either you got something wrong, either you forgot the main rainbow ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido Actually, I only know the color spectrum ranges from infra-red to ultra-violet and I admit I have *no idea how rainbows are colored*. :-O So I got it backwards??

Comment: Well I'm no expert, but according to my fast reading of  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow, the spectrum is backwards because we see its reflection in the rain drops, except the more rare case of double rainbows where the main rainbow is itself reflected (so the spectrum is forward)

Comment: @Kaiido, Fair Enough...since I can't change mother nature (!), I'll reverse the colors in my demo. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Draw one using HSL color cycle-through (red should be on the outside):

Normalizing current bar on max number of bars gives a value that can be used for the Hue component (300-360°, lower the upper angle to reduce the bands). Then simply decrease radius for each bar with the thickness of the line -1 to keep a small overlap to cover anti-aliasing from the previous bar.

The smoothness can be increased by setting higher max bars and reduce the line-width (or calculate the line-width based on total radius range).

### Example

[image: snapshot]

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), bars = 20, i = 0, radius = 140;
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

for(i = 0; i < bars; i++, radius -= ctx.lineWidth - 1) {      // increase bar, reduce radius
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c.width * 0.5, c.height, radius, 0, Math.PI, true); // half circle
  ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + (i / bars * 300) + ",90%,50%)";  // set color using HSL
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```